# how can i check request , body in retrofit flutter api calls

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit, flutter-dependencies

I have tried retrofit for app call in flutter application
but
I couldn't find a way to log baseapi+route with the request body.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Since retrofit is the dio client generator, you could use the [Prett Dio Logger](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/pretty_dio_logger) in the Dio interceptor to view the request, response and both.